# Reporting Services across multiple sub-sites

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I have several sub-sites on our new Sharepoint site.

We are moving our reporting services reports from a set up using an old single `SSRS` web portal, into Sharepoint.

What is the recommended structure to use?

```
1. A document library within each sub-site for SSRS reports.
2. A single library at the sub-sites root.
```

If we go for option two how do we then reference relevant reports within each sub-site?

Comment: How are you planning on displaying the reports? Using the ReportViewer web part?

Are the reports the same on each site, or specific to each sub-site?

Do you want to be able to replace/update a report on a specific sub-site, without effecting that same report on other sites? or do you want to replace/update a report once and have the changes show up everywhere that report is referenced?

Comment: @lwbecker2 all reports need to be update-able and the updates should filter through to all instances and references. Is the reportViewer webpart the recommended way to view reports in SP2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you added the information that you would like the changes and updates to filter through to all instances of the report in other sites, I would recommend a centralized approach.

You can choose to expose the document library that holds the reports (.rdl) file and then users can open the report, or you can add a report viewer web part on a page and have it automatically render the report (the path to the report file is in the web part properties).

I would put the reports in document library at the site collection root and then have pages in my sub-sites with the report viewer web part loaded on them. When you swap out or update the report in the central library, all report viewer web parts that are viewing the report would be automatically updated.

Comment: +1 sounds like a reasonable approach. I've not played around with the report viewer web part yet - does it add quite a bit of value rather than having simply a link to a report file?

Comment: Good question. Some added value is that it allows to you have multiple reports on a page if you want (mutliple report viewer web parts on a page), it allows you to place it inside a page with other information around it instead of only showing the report content.  It can also accept report parameters using other connected web parts as parameter sources if that is useful you.